# Plethora of php.ini files

Tags: php

I installed PHP on an Ubuntu server to find there are six php.ini files in my file system.

I'd like to get this right, so can anyone explain what the distinct purpose is of each file?

My hunch is that `/etc/php5` are the actual files being used by PHP, and `/usr/share/php5` are suggestions for how you should edit `etc` depending on your environment (so you would copy/paste stuff from `usr` into `etc`, but I may be wrong about this). It is also unclear what `production-dist` and `production.cli` implies compared to `production`.

```
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-development
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production-dist
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.cli
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: production-dist most likely is there as a backup for default production ini file. cli means command line. you can check which php.ini is active with phpinfo();

Comment: @JurisMalinens wouldn't that be an answer

Comment: yeh put this is an answer so we can vote on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

production-dist most likely is there as a backup for default production ini file. cli means command line. you can check which php.ini is active with phpinfo();