# What's the difference between php.ini-production and php.ini-production-dist in /usr/share/php5?

Tags: php, ubuntu, configuration

I've been using the same php.ini file for well over 10 years, periodically merging the changes from new PHP versions into it. Since Breezy (5.10), I've more or less followed the Debian/Ubuntu conventions (with some modifications), including the split between the CLI and Apache versions.

As a result, what I have in /etc/php5 has always been slightly different from what the distribution provides as a default. Now I need to know exactly what the differences are. Luckily, the default ini files are still available in /usr/share/php5. I understand that the distro default is "production" (which makes sense), but I see more than one production file:

```
# ls -l /usr/share/php5/php.ini*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66K Jul 15 20:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-development
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65K Jul 15 20:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 64K Jul 15 20:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production-dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 64K Jul 15 20:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.cli
```

What I would like to know:

- What *exactly* is the purpose of each of these files?
- In a vanilla install, which of these end up as /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini?

My guess would be:

- php.ini-development: pretty obvious - stricter error handling, errors are displayed, no legacy bug workarounds. Can be copied or symlinked to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for development.
- php.ini-production.cli: originally identical to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini?

The difference between php.ini-production and php.ini-production-dist has me stumped.
For reference, the differences are:

```
# diff php.ini-production php.ini-production-dist 
213c213
< short_open_tag = On
---
> short_open_tag = Off
316c316
< disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
---
> disable_functions =
407c407
< memory_limit = 128M
---
> memory_limit = 32M
1407c1407
< session.gc_probability = 0
---
> session.gc_probability = 1
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108063/plethora-of-php-ini-files) has been asked here, but the answers didn't contain what I'd like to know.

I'm currently using Ubuntu and Kubuntu Raring (13.04).